# I find the error while running code which is elif n == 2

Tags: python

```
def fibonacci(n):
   if n == 1:
      return 1
   elif n == 2:
      return 1
    elif n > 2:
       return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
     for n in range(1, 11):
    print(n, ":", fibonacci(n))
```

Comment: When asking python code questions, imo it's essential to show us the indentation as it is on your editor, otherwise problems like this can't be found quickly.

Answer (score 2):

There are indentation problems in your code, remember: in Python whitespace is very, very important! Try this:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n == 2:
        return 1
    elif n > 2: # your indentation was incorrect in this line
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

for n in range(1, 11):
    print(n, ":", fibonacci(n))
```